# Removing RelativeLinkResolution on angular upgrade to v15 does not load div component

Tags: c#, .net, angular, upgrade, angular15

The page contains a navigation bar with drop down menus. If I select the first dropdown option, a list of reports is displayed, and on clicking second option, another list of reports is displayed. Since I have upgraded to angular, the first option does not work until unless i have selected the second option.

In App-routing.module.ts=>
@MgModule({

````
exports: [RouterModule]
}]```

After removing 'RelativeLinkResolution':
In App-routing.module.ts=>
```@MgModule({
imports:[RouteModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash:true,on SameUrlNavigation:'reload'})],
exports: [RouterModule]
}]
````

Comment: Create a testable example in stackblitz for us to understand it better.